# Keep console open to listen info from remote server in C# dot.net core

Tags: c#, console, .net-core

I created a console dot net core project and it listens to a websocket server and it displays information received.

```
        var url = $"wss://serverurl";

        var ws = new WebSocket(url);

        ws.OnOpen += (s, ev) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("web socket opened");
        };

        ws.OnMessage += (s, ev) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Data);
        };

        ws.OnClose += (s, ev) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("web socket will be closed");
        };

        ws.OnError += (s, ev) =>
        {
            ws.Close();
        };

        ws.Connect();
```

But the console will close immediately after `ws.Connect()` is executed.

Or if I put `Console.Read()` then console will wait for input key and won't display info here anymore.

How to proceed here ?

I created console app to be executed on Windows or even Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while(true)
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

to sleep indefinitely in mail thread.

Comment: So, if I will do that, any message which will come from `OnMessage` will be processed after 1 second, right ?

Answer (score 0):

This project is a good demo for C# to always listen for a request on a port.

The code is here:
https://github.com/Anduin2017/Genji/blob/master/Genji/Models/GenjiServer.cs#L64

```
    private async Task Listening()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
            try
            {
                listener.Start();
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine($"Genji server started at http://localhost:{Port}/");
                while (true)
                {
                    var tcp = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    var stream = tcp.GetStream();
                    Excute(stream).GetAwaiter();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Recorder.RecordException(e);
                listener.Stop();
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task Excute(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        Recorder.RecordIncoming();
        try
        {
            await Calculate(stream);
        }
        catch (RequestTerminatedException)
        {
            Recorder.Print("A request was terminated!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            Recorder.RecordException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used event driven notifications ... I don't listen at every X seconds ...